# set_time_limit has no effect even with safe_mode=Off

Tags: php, apache

I migrated my server and have several php script using `set_time_limit`.

I don't want to set a global time limit in the `php.ini` but `set_time_limit` doesn't work anymore.
I read somewhere that it doesn't work with `safe_mode` so I checked and it is not enabled. What can I do ?

Comment: But [it should still be working](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in PHP 7.x

Comment: Define "doesn't work anymore"?

Comment: The script stop after the time defined in the php.ini and in fact I realised that this is the same for ignore_user_abort